# Orchard CMS batch migrations for multiple tenants

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am setting up an Orchard site that will eventually be housing hundreds of tenants.  The on-boarding process will be manual (ie a human will set the new tenant up using the Orchard admin UI) however I can see Module updates (via DataMigrations) being a problem if I would have to go through each tenant and upgrade manually through the admin UI.

Is it possible to script this kind of Module upgrade?

cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest 1.x source, migrations are automatic.

Comment: whenever i write a migration UpdateFromX, i have to go into the admin UI and "upgrade" the Module manually, is there something i'm missing?

Comment: That's because you're not running the latest 1.x.

Comment: i've been running 1.3.9 - when you say latest 1.x do you mean 1.3.10?

Comment: No. The latest in the 1.x branch on Mercurial, not the latest release on Codeplex.

Comment: Ahh i see, thanks!  Any idea when this change might make it into an official release?